# Keep children when replacing tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to replace a form tag without deleting its children. For example, I would like to convert this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

To this:

```
<p>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</p>
```

But instead I get:

```
<p></p>
```

This is how I'm trying to do it right now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '<form><input type="text"/><input type="text"/></form>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

old_form = soup.find('form')
new_form = soup.new_tag('p')

old_form.replace_with(new_form)  
print soup
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `.name` property works for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '<form><input type="text"/><input type="text"/></form>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

form = soup.find('form')
form.name = 'p'

print form.prettify()
<p>
 <input type="text"/>
 <input type="text"/>
</p>
```